# Android WebView stops working when clicking a website button

Tags: java, android

I've implemented the following [calendar](https://schoolibox.com/sandbox/app/eventos.php?user_id=1) inside a WebView in my Android app. 
When I press specifically the "month" button the WebView freezes, and all WebViews (in other activities) stop loading.

I have notice that this happens just in particular devices. For example: MI 2A lite (Android 9).

I've debugged directly the website and it doesn't throw any (relevant) error.

Also I have debugged the WebView using chrome://inspect/#devices and there's no error too.

So I guess it's not a problem with the website.
I have also use Android Profiler and find out that the app is still detecting the clicks events in the WebView, but it remains freeze anyway.

And also debugged using Logcat but there doesn`t seems to be any related log.

I've implemented many WebViews before without problem, and as I mentioned this just happens on specific devices

```
web_calificaciones.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_calificaciones.setFocusable(true);
        web_calificaciones.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        web_calificaciones.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        web_calificaciones.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        web_calificaciones.loadUrl(urlToLoad);

        web_calificaciones.setWebViewClient(new CalendarActivity.myWebclient());
        web_calificaciones.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){

                if(progress==100){
                    progressbar_calificaciones.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    container_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
            }
        });
        web_calificaciones.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

I don't know if it's might be a memory or version problem.

Comment: Any luck with that? I'm going through the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd try not to set the setRenderPriority to HIGH. Setting priorities to high should always be considered carefully. I don't think a calender needs that specific setting. Also, setEnableSmoothTransition should only be used if really needed. Try to comment these out and I'm happy to hear if that helped!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that didn't solve the issue :( I also discover that when it freezes, when trying to reload for second time the onProgressChanged method just get to 10 and get stuck. In all activities with WebView